# Function call instructions explanation

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

So, I have recently started understanding x86 assembly language. 
I made an object file of the following C++ code and used objdump -S to view the .o file created.

```
void func(){
    int d,f;
    d=10;
    f=1;    
}

int main(){
    int x;
    x = 1;
}
```

I got the following assembly code :

```
t1.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_Z4funcv>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   c7 45 f8 0a 00 00 00    movl   $0xa,-0x8(%rbp)
   b:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  12:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  13:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000014 <main>:
  14:   55                      push   %rbp
  15:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  18:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  1f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  24:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  25:   c3                      retq
```

Can someone what exactly the assembly code instructions are doing? I understand that push and pop are used to store and remove from stack . But what is the exact use the instruction is doing?

Comment: [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) is a nice way to visualize how the code maps to the instructions.

Comment: It saves the frame. So each function must know its frame,thererore it pushes its base adress beore doing anything else, and receives it before returning to caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calling convention mandates which registers need to be preserved, and that includes `rbp`. This means, if your function wants to use `rbp` for its own purposes, it must make sure that it holds the same value at function exit as it did at function entry. A convenient way to achieve this is to `push` and `pop` it.

What does it use `rbp` for? Historically, the `bp` register has been used to mark the stack frame and to access local variables and function arguments. One of the reasons was that in old 16 bit code, you couldn't address relative to the stack pointer `sp`. Also, knowing the stack frame boundaries can be helpful in debugging and stack unwinding. In 32 and nowadays in 64 bit code, you can address relative to the stack pointer, and debugging is aided by specialized debug information which works fine even without a frame pointer. As such, it has become common practice to disable frame pointer, effectively freeing one more register for general use. This code has not been compiled with optimization enabled, which is why you see `rbp` being used.

Okay, let's see what is happening. Line `0` saves `rbp` as discussed above. Line `1` then saves the current value of the stack pointer there, marking the stack frame. Lines `4` and `b` simply initialize your two variables. Note that they reside in the 128 byte red zone under the stack pointer that the x86-64 ABI allows you to use without allocating. Normally you'd see a `sub rsp, size-of-locals` kind of instruction to allocate the space from the stack. Line `12` restores the original value of `rbp`, and finally line `13` returns to the caller.

The `main` function is pretty similar, the only interesting difference is on line `1f` which loads `0` into `eax`. That register is used to pass return values back to the caller.

This was just a quick peek into the topic of calling conventions. For the deeper details refer to the appropriate documentation.

Comment: Use `-fomit-frame-pointer` to tell gcc not use the old fashioned `*bp`. When you say "This code has not been compiled with optimization enabled", you should specify which one you're refering to. I don't consider `-fomit-frame-pointer` as an optimization, for example. Instead, if the code were compiled with a concrete optimization level, it'd be a `xor-ret` because it doesn't do anything observable. I hope you got the point.